# How can I achieve multiple selections in Simple Column chart in amCharts

Tags: crossfilter, amcharts4

```
series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function (ev) {
        var selected_wkcntr = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.key; 
        var typeDimension = ndf.dimension(function (d) {
            return d.order_type;
        })
        console.log(typeDimension)
        catagoryDimension.filter(function (d) {
            return d === selected_wkcntr;
        })
        var dimension3 = ndf.dimension(function (d) {
            return d.ui_status;
        })
        uistatusPiechart(dimension3);
        var WorkCenterBasedData = catagoryDimension.bottom(Infinity);
        charttable(WorkCenterBasedData)
        var planDatesDimension = ndf.dimension(function (d) {
            return d.production_start_date
        })
        newchart(typeDimension);
        lineChart(planDatesDimension);
    })
}
```

This is my code for handling the Click event on the column. Here based on selected workcenter i am filtering various charts such as Status, Order type etc..
I am using Simple Column chart in amCharts. I have a requirement where data sets to be filtered on base of column selection. I am able to do it with single column selection. I want to know how multiple selection of columns. I have used crossfilter to feed data to the charts.

Comment: What have you tried? Please add related codes you have.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: I don’t know amCharts, but you ordinarily wouldn’t create crossfilter dimensions on response to a click event. Dimensions are expensive and your page will get slow. Once you have your list of `wkcntrs`, say, then you can change your filter function to `wkcntrs.includes(d)`. So that answers the crossfilter side of the question, not sure how you get the multiple selection from amCharts.